# Webpack + sass gerando style.css

Tags: javascript, css3, sass, webpack

Porque o webpack na hora de realizar o **extract** nos arquivos **.scss**, ele cria o arquivo **styles.css** tudo certo na pasta **dist/css**, mas ele retira as aspas e pontos do caminho de uma foto por exmplo: `background: url("../img/back.jpg")`. 
Deixando `background: url(img/back.jpg)`, só que assim não é possível carrega a imagem no browser.

**Webpack.config.js**

```
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");
const ExtractTextPlugin = require("extract-text-webpack-plugin");

const HWPConfig = new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
  template: __dirname + "/src/index.html",
  file: "index.html",
  inject: "body"
});

module.exports = {
  entry: ["./src/main.js"],
  output: {
    filename: "bundle.js",
    path: __dirname + "/dist"
  },
  devtool: "source-map",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: "babel-loader",
        query: {
          presets: [["es2015", { modules: false }]]
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: "style-loader",
          use: [
            {
              loader: "css-loader",
              options: {
                sourceMap: true
              }
            },
            {
              loader: "sass-loader",
              options: {
                sourceMap: true
              }
            }
          ]
        })
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg)$/,
        use: {
          loader: "file-loader",
          options: {
            name: "[name].[ext]",
            outputPath: "img/"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [HWPConfig, new ExtractTextPlugin("css/styles.css")]
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesse caso precisa incluir o publicPath

```
module.exports = {
entry: ["./src/main.js"],
output: {
filename: "bundle.js",
path: __dirname + "/dist",
publicPath: "/"
},
```